# Remove LVM partition that overlap with my windows partition

Tags: windows, partition, lvm, parrot-os

So this happends when I want to setup dual-boot ParrotOS and Windows. When I want to install Parrot, I accidentally select 'use all disk and setup LVM' (not encripted) and I noticed that and click cancel but the LVM already been setup. Can I revert the LVM setup or get my data out from the windows partition?

Thanks!

**Edit 1**
I check my windows partition on ParrotOS live using TestDisk, the files are intact and I'm copying the files to removable flashdrive as a backup. Is there anything I can do to make my partition bootable inside LVM? or how can I extract the partition to direct partition not inside LVM?

Answer (score 0):

After asking on other technology forums, I decided to format my hard drive and reinstall windows.